# Node.js as a forwarding proxy but changing the URL path?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

How do i let node.js act as a proxy and forward all requests sent from one server to another server but stripping /couchdb/ from the url path so that for example POST /couchdb/mydatabase will be POST /mydatabase. And when it receives the response it should send it to the first server.

All I have done is this (using express) to get all requests where the URL path starts with /couchdb/

```
app.all(/^\/couchdb\/(?:.)*/, function(req, res) {

});
```

Could someone guide me through. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

have a look at [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). you can use it like this:

```
  var http = require('http'),
  httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
  httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
         // Put your custom server logic here (eg rewrite url/header,...)
      proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {host: 'localhost', port: 9000});
  }).listen(8000);
```

Comment: I'm guessing http-proxy's api has changed since this was posted. To get this to work, I had to use: proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {host: 'localhost', port: 9000});

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as now it is mandatory to pass some kind of a target or a forward field in the options. Running the above code gives me `Must provide valid url for Target`